# Specify schema and database only once

Tags: sql-server

Is there some kind of namespace syntax so that I won't have to specify database and schema for every table?
Dunno if it's MS SQL or MS SQL Management Studio issue.

Pseudo-example:

```
using DatabaseName.SchemaName
SELECT * FROM Tablename1, Tablename2, Tablename3
```

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM DatabaseName.SchemaName.Tablename1, DatabaseName.SchemaName.Tablename2, DatabaseName.SchemaName.Tablename3
```

Comment: Your names are the wrong way around. Three-part table names are `Database.Schema.Table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `USE` keywaord for the database at the top of the script if the database is same  for the whole script

```
USE Databasename
SELECT * FROM Schemaname.Tablename1, Schemaname.Tablename2, Schemaname.Tablename3
```

You can also set the default schema like this:

> Security > Logins > (right click) user > Properties > User Mapping >
>   Default Schema

Also one more option is [alter your user with the default schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx):

```
ALTER USER SO_July14_Reader WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = SO_July14
```

Comment: Despite the schema can be skipped with the default schema setting, it's very useful when naming objects (for instance, it allows same object name for different schemas). I think that indicating the right schema always in our queries is a good practice to follow.

Comment: Not always. For instance: I have a website on MS SQL and it's pretty tedious every time to add scnema.database when checking/testing/updating queries in scripts. It wouldn't be a problem if there wasn't DEV and LIVE versions of sites with different databases. That means I alwasy have to remember to change schema.database names when moving changes from DEV enviroment to LIVE.

Comment: A schema is an aggregator of objects on a database.. Why you're speaking about environment? And why you're speaking aobut different databases? I'm a little bit confused..

Comment: 1) No matter whether it is schema.database or database.schema - the problem remains the same. 2) I have two enviroments: one where everything is developed and tested and the second which users use. Databases are separated for obvious reasons.